# PHP Array insert into MySQL table as individual rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert, multidimensional-array

I am trying to insert multiple rows in a MySQL table from PHP arrays. I managed with with help of other members to get set of values in a pair of brackets but when i try to insert this i get "**Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**" I donot know where am i going wrong. my codes are as below: (The number of values i get vary according to user input)

```
    $docno1=array();
    $serialno = array();
    $acc_name = array();
    $debit = array();
    $credit = array();

    for ($i=1;$i<=$rowcount;$i++)
    {
    //echo 'Accountname'.$i.' :'.($_GET['accname'.$i]).'<br>';
    $docno1 [] = ($_GET['docno']);
    array_unshift($docno1,"");
    unset($docno1[0]);

    $serialno [] = $i;
    array_unshift($serialno,"");
    unset($serialno[0]);

    $acc_name[] = ($_GET['accname'.$i]);
    array_unshift($acc_name,"");
    unset($acc_name[0]);

    $debit[] = ($_GET['DrAmount'.$i]);
    array_unshift($debit,"");
    unset($debit[0]);

    $credit[] = ($_GET['CrAmount'.$i]);
    array_unshift($credit,"");
    unset($credit[0]);

    }


    $sum_dr = array_sum ($debit);
    $sum_cr = array_sum ($credit);





    echo ' values of $multi<br>';
    $multi = array(
    ($docno1),
    ($serialno), //Array for a row of fields
    ($acc_name),
    ($debit),
    ($credit),
    ($docno1)

    );

    print_r($multi);

    $new = array();
    foreach($multi as $key=>$value) {
    $new[] = "'".implode("','", $value)."'";

    }
    echo '<br>Values of $new <br>';
    print_r($new);

    $query = "(".implode("), (",$new).")";
    echo $query.'<br>';


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO docitems (`docno`,`itemno`,`accountname`,`debit`,`credit`, `picrefno`) VALUES ".$query.";") or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());


    echo "Inserted successfully";
    die;
```

**The results i get are :**

```
      values of $multi
      Array
      (
      [0] => Array
      (
      [1] => 3434
      [2] => 3434
      )

      [1] => Array
      (
      [1] => 1
      [2] => 2
      )

      [2] => Array
      (
      [1] => Lemon
      [2] => Kidney Beans
      )

      [3] => Array
      (
      [1] => 20
      [2] => 10
      )

      [4] => Array
      (
      [1] => 0
      [2] => 0
      )

      [5] => Array
      (
      [1] => 3434
      [2] => 3434
      )

      )

      Values of $new 
      Array
      (
      [0] => '3434','3434'
      [1] => '1','2'
      [2] => 'Lemon','Kidney Beans'
      [3] => '20','10'
      [4] => '0','0'
      [5] => '3434','3434'
      )
      ('3434','3434'), ('1','2'), ('Lemon','Kidney Beans'), ('20','10'), ('0','0'), ('3434','3434')
      Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Comment: That is an SQL error, no? Can we see the full statement? It has nothing to do with PHP if the generated SQL isn't valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if you are mapping your array the wrong way round. You're trying to add two records with six fields each, but what you're actually putting into the SQL statement are six records with two fields each.

This is why MySQL is complaining -- because you've told it you want to update six fields, but in each of the records you've given it, you've only specified two fields.

You need to build your array differently.

I assume that `$docno1`, `$serialno`, `$acc_name`, `$debit` and `$credit` will always all have the same number of array elements (it appears from your code that you are assuming this, so I'll follow you in your assumption).

In that case, you need to build your array something like this:

```
$multi = array();
foreach($docno1 as $key=>value) {
    $multi[] = array(
        $docno1[$key],
        $serialno[$key], //Array for a row of fields
        $acc_name[$key],
        $debit[$key],
        $credit[$key],
        $docno1[$key])
}
```

Replace the block in your code where you set `$multi` with this, and your program should work.

Look at what `print_r($multi)` looks like now, and you'll see the difference.

(note, there are more efficient ways of writing your whole program than this, but I've focused on giving you a drop-in replacement for this specific bit, to help show you where you were going wrong, rather than simply rewriting the whole program for you)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hoooooooooooo Hoo!, I dont have words to say thank you. you have solved the mystry. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO docitems (`docno`,`itemno`,`accountname`,`debit`,`credit`, `picrefno`) VALUES ".$query.";") or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
```

You are trying to insert something into 6 fields, so that `$query` string must have 6 values in it, or you get this error.

You have a lot of `$query`'s that are 2 values. And that's not 6

Comment: I've given you +1 for explaining what the error is telling him, but I don't think it tells the whole story; the root cause of the problem is that he's getting his array the wrong way round (6x2 rather than 2x6 elements); see my answer for an explanation of this and some code to help him see where he's going wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the error is occurring when trying to insert a row to your table, try specifying the list of fields, in the insert query -- this way, the number of data in the `values` clause will match the number of expected columns.

Else, MySQL expects six columns : it expects the specific inserts -- for which you didn't specify a value.